# SwaggerUI Docker support for two api files (locally)

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to create a Swagger UI configuration to show several of my apis. They are not hosted publicly, the definition files are in my local file system. I'm using swagger ui with docker. I run it with the following command:

```sh
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v $(pwd)/_build:/spec swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

In `_build` directory is where I have my yaml spec files. This is the `swagger-config.yaml` config file:

```yaml
urls:
  - /spec/openapi2.yaml
  - /spec/openapi.yaml
plugins:
  - topbar
```

I have also tried:

```yaml
urls:
  - url: /spec/openapi2.yaml
    name: API1
  - url: /spec/openapi.yaml
    name: API2
plugins:
  - topbar
```

After running it, this is what I see:

[image]

That's the default API of Swagger UI, so I suppose there's an error in my configuration. I have tried several things, but they have not worked and I do not seem to find any good documentation about the `swagger-config.yaml` configuration file.

Any idea to make it work with several APIs?

Comment: The comments in the Swagger UI issue tracker say that the config file should be JSON, and YAML config is actually is not supported: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6019#issuecomment-768492996

Comment: You're right! They should document that. In the docs it said yaml in fact. Can you post that as an answer please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [comments](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6019#issuecomment-768492996) in the Swagger UI issue tracker, the Docker version needs the config file in the JSON format rather than YAML.

Try using this `swagger-config.json`:

```json
{
  "urls": [
    {
      "url": "/spec/openapi2.yaml",
      "name": "API1"
    },
    {
      "url": "/spec/openapi.yaml",
      "name": "API2"
    }
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "topbar"
  ]
}
```

Also add `-e CONFIG_URL=/path/to/swagger-config.json` to the `docker run` command.